# Geoserver error during loading pyramid iamges

Tags: geoserver, tiles, image-pyramids

I've add geoserver plugin ImagePyramid and generate tiles by Maperitive. Next I try add this tiles into Geoserver as datasource, but when I click publish after loading I've got this error :

```
    org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@3a9445a7 on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:865)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:366)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$8.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:280)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:84)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:588)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException: Can't transform envelope.
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1242)
    at org.geoserver.data.util.CoverageStoreUtils.getWGS84LonLatEnvelope(CoverageStoreUtils.java:306)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:921)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:859)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:356)
    ... 111 more
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: No transformation available from system "EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]" to "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]".
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:389)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.java:258)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1240)
    ... 115 more
```

This happen after I delete last level, becaouse during loading level 17, I've got a lot these error:

```
2017-02-01 03:51:00,761 WARN [gce.image] - Could not find a world transform file for 44910, assuming the identity transform
...
```

I try find this images in last level, and there are here. So I try delete last level and publish it without him and this casue upper error. Any ideas what I do wrong ?

Comment: GeoServer is trying to re-project data into EPSG:4326 but it does not know what is the native projection `No transformation available from system "EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]" to "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]"`.

Comment: can you give me advice how to fix it ?